# Anyone know how to prevent sublime text 2 tag completion in the CF plugin for specific tags

Tags: coldfusion, sublimetext2

Just like the title says, I would like to prevent certain tags from from adding a closing tag.  Specifically `cfprocparam`. Each time I write

```
<cfprocparam value="">
```

sublime adds

```
</cfprocparam>
```

I know that I can change

`"auto_close_cfml": true,` **to** `"auto_close_cfml": false,`

But I don't want the behavior removed all together since it is very helpful in the case of `cfif` for example.  I just don't want it for certain tags.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a closing slash prevents auto closing the tag:
`<cfprocparam value="" />`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I know that works but I am specifically wanting to know if there is a was to disable the behavior for specific tags

Comment: You can post a feature request for that in the GitHub issues if you want.

Comment: [GitHub issues](https://github.com/SublimeText/ColdFusion/issues?direction=desc&sort=created&state=open)